# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value must be a decimal number.']

Tags: python, django, database, migrate, makemigrations

I got this error while migrating
here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from decimal import Decimal
# Create your models here.
class Pharmacy(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField()
    feed=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=1,default=Decimal('1.0'),null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
class feedback(models.Model):
    phid=models.ForeignKey(Pharmacy,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5.,decimal_places=0,default=Decimal('1.0'),null=True)
```

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value must be a decimal number.']

I did makemigrations with no errors

Answer (score 0):

`max_digits=5.` => `max_digits=5`